# RxSwift wrapper for textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:interaction:

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want to have a method to intercept links tap in a `UITextView` through `RxSwift` something similar to:

```
textView.rx.didTapLink
        .subscribe(onNext: { link, characterRange, interaction in
            // handle link tap
        })
```

I saw there is no implementation for [delegate forwarding](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/53cd723d40d05177e790c8c34c36cec7092a6106/RxCocoa/iOS/Proxies/RxTextViewDelegateProxy.swift) for the [textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:interaction:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview?language=objc) method so I presume I must add an extension for the `RxTextViewDelegateProxy` to implement the missing delegate method but don't know how to continue from there or if what I want is event possible without forking `RxSwift` but it should be possible I presume. I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Because the method in question returns a value (the OS pulls data from your app using this method,) it doesn't fit well with the Rx "push data" ecosystem. The appropriate way to implement this is as follows:

Given:

```
class MyTextViewDelegate: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith url: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        return true // do what you think best here.
    }
}
```

You can connect it to the text view like this:

```
textView.rx.delegate.setForwardToDelegate(MyTextViewDelegate(), retainDelegate: true)
```

Using the forwardToDelegate allows you to continue to use the push type delegate methods using the Rx system.